# Target x86 in net461

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, x86, .net-framework-version, .net-4.6.1

I'm building a .NET Core Web Application that **needs to run on an x86 platform**. Currently, I'm using net461. I guess by default, the application is targeting win7-x64. I'm using Visual Studio 2015.

[image]

How do I change it to x86?

**Things I've tried:**

I tried listing x86 as the Active solution platform (didn't work):

[image]

I tried listed win10-x86 as the runtime in the project.json file (didn't work):

```
"frameworks": {
    "net461": {}
},
"runtimes": {
    "win10-x86": {}
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you were changing is just for debugging in different frameworks, not actually changing the target framework.

Now there are a few different ways to do this, but I'll include the way MSDN recommends in this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185328.aspx

**1. Go to Build menu and select Configuration Manager.**

[image]

**2. Select the Platform dropdown click "New"**

[image]

**3. Select the desired platform from the drop down.**

I hope that helps! =)